# How to call MATLAB program from the java application

Tags: java, matlab, processbuilder

I am trying to call matlab executable file from java application 
i am try 2 option:

```
Process p=new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\Dexter\\Documents\\MATLAB\\Project.exe").start();

Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Dexter\\Documents\\MATLAB\\Project.exe");
```

... these 2 options are work properly for another application like chrome, eclipse, et cetera
pls suggest the solution

Comment: Are you shure `Project.exe` is the right binary? I'd expect you call `MATLAB\bin\matlab.exe` When using Linux, I have to pass `-desktop` otherwise it starts a terminal session. Some hints: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102082-how-do-i-call-matlab-from-the-dos-prompt

Comment: Does `project.exe` run from windows command line? Get the error and standard output of the process, it probably explains what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are trying to run an executable exported from Matlab, within Java. I am not sure that this is going to work...

What you can do is to use the [matlabcontrol](https://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/) library in order to open a session with Matlab and then you will be able to run Matlab commands directly, from Java, or run a Matlab script from Java, by giving some inputs and taking back the result from Matlab. I have created a server which does all the aforementioned, in Java, and using matlabcontrol library to connect with Matlab. You can find it here:

[Connect Java with Matlab](https://github.com/panosvas/IndoorPositioningServer)

Let me know if you need any further clarification.